# Filling Constants with methods

Tags: ruby

I'm making a "connect four" application with Ruby.

I have the following class called `win`

```
class Win

  def up
    #
  end

  def down
    #
  end

  def diagonal_one
    #
  end

  def diagonal_two
    #
  end

end
```

I'd like to make a constant like so:

```
  CONDITIONS = [up, down, diagonal_one, diagonal_two]
```

so I could easily check against `Win::CONDITIONS` - but this approach throws `undefined local variable or method 'up' for Win:Class (NameError)`.  Is there a way to put methods in constants?  If not, what's a better way to do this?

Comment: You could define the methods as class methods. But it would try to execute those methods during the class load. You could instead populate the value directly. It would help if you could give an example of how your method implementation will look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to define an array of symbols:

```
 CONDITIONS = %i[up down diagonal_one diagonal_two]
```

and whenever you need to call a method on an object, call `send(...)` on the object.

Answer (score 1):

This will work as you expect, but you will have these methods as `Win` class methods:

```
class Win
  class << self

    def up
      #
    end

    def down
      #
    end

    def diagonal_one
      #
    end

    def diagonal_two
      #
    end
  end
end
```

You have the error because you try to use `Win` instance methods in the context of `Win` class.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the difference of class/instance context, writing `up` invokes that method, which may be not your intent.

You can store name of method with a symbol `:up`, and invoke it like

```
a_win_instance.send :up
```